# Symfony 2 form optional image

Tags: php, forms, symfony, image-uploading, symfony-forms

I have an issue with my Symfony 2 form and my image upload.

I created a form :

```
$form = $formFactory->create(new PlaceType($this->_em), $place, array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'status' => $place->getStatus()
        ));
```

In `PlaceType.php` :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
            $builder->add('images', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new ImageType($this->em),
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'data' => array(new Image())));
    }
```

In `ImageType.php` :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('file', 'file', array('required' => false));
}
```

It's working very well, but when I don't fill the fiel field, I have an exception threw because file infos are missing.

I would like to make this field optional. I tried a lot of solutions, but none is working.

EDIT (my entity code `image.php`) :

```
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload() {
        if (null !== $this->file) {
            $this->link = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
            $this->name = 'name';
            $this->sort = 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload() {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }
        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->link);

        unset($this->file);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload() {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath() {
        return null === $this->link ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->link;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir() {
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir() {
        return 'uploads/media';
    }
```

EDIT 2 (my AJAX controller code) :

```
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em->persist($place);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

As you can see, I can't control the persist neither the flush, so, I can't manage my image upload.

EDIT 3 :

I use an `ArrayCollection` to keep the old images from the database and add the new one, here is my code in the `AJAX controller` :

```
$originalArray = new ArrayCollection();
foreach ($place->getImages() as $images) {
    $originalArray->add($images);
    $place->removeImage($images);
}
```

And later :

```
foreach ($originalArray as $images) {
    $place->addImage($images);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us how you use the form after it has been submited?

Comment: I have an AJAX controller, and the upload of the picture is made with `$form->handleRequest($request);`. Inside my image entity, I have some functions for the preUpdate, postPersist, etc.

Comment: Ok, can you show us the exact error message, and the line who threw the error ?

Comment: The exception : `An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO image (name, link, sort, status_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null`

In my database, name is not null by default. So, the error is normal, but I would like to get around it.

Comment: Are you saving the image in database even if it's not filled ?

Comment: When I started to implement the upload, I didn't think about the optional upload of the picture. So, with the `$form->handleRequest($request);` , my `AJAX controller` try to save it in the database everytime, even if it's not filled. But I would like to change this behavior..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75127/discussion-between-med-and-g4briel).

Comment: So, we didn't find any solution in the chat, I'm waiting for others. Thanks by advance

Comment: Please edit your question adding the further details found in these comments

Comment: Hi @Jean, I just added 2 edits.